# How to have python recognize correct value in my code? Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

```
for i in range(n): 
    while len(dictionary)>0:
        choice = random.choice(list(dictionary.keys()))
        correctAnswer = dictionary[choice]
        print("English: ",choice)
        guess = input("Spanish: ")
        dictionary.pop(choice)
        if guess == correctAnswer:
            print("\nCorrect!\n")
        else:
            print("Incorrect\n")
            wrongAnswers.append(choice)
        break
print("\nYou missed", len(wrongAnswers), "words\n")
```

Hi, I am trying to create a vocabulary test on python. My code works up until this chunk. After the program prompts the user for their guess, the program will say it is incorrect even if it is the right answer. Is there an error in this code? How can I get around this?

This is what it looks like:
English:  white
Spanish: blanco
Incorrect

English:  purple
Spanish: morado
Incorrect

Thanks!

Full Code:

```
def main(): 

import random 
wrongAnswers = [] 

print("Hello, Welcome to the Spanish-English vocabulary test.") 
print(" ")
print("\nAfter the test, this program will create a file of the incorrect answers for you to view")

print("\nTo start, please select from the following options: \nverbs.txt \nadjectives.txt \ncolors.txt \nschool.txt \nplaces.txt") #sk

while True: #SK
    selection = input("Insert your selection: ").lower() #user inputs selection #sk
    if selection == "verbs.txt" or selection == "adjectives.txt" or selection == 'colors.txt' or selection == 'school.txt' or selection == 'places.txt':
        print("You have chosen", selection, "to be tested on.")
        break
    if False:
        print("try again.")
        selection = input("Insert your selection: ").lower()
        break



file = open(selection, 'r') 
dictionary = {}
with file as f:
    for line in f:
        items = line.rstrip("\n").split(",")
        key, values = items[0], items[1:]
        dictionary[key] = values


length = len(dictionary)
print(length,'entries found')

n= int(input("How many words would you like to be tested on: "))
while n > length:
    print("Invalid. There are only" ,length, "entries")
    n= int(input("How many words would you like to be tested on: "))
print("You have chosen to be tested on",n, "words.\n")



for i in range(n): 
    while len(dictionary)>0:
        choice = random.choice(list(dictionary.keys()))
        correctAnswer = dictionary[choice]
        print("English: ",choice)
        guess = input("Spanish: ")
        dictionary.pop(choice)
        if guess == correctAnswer:
            print("\nCorrect!\n")
        else:
            print("Incorrect\n")
            wrongAnswers.append(choice)
        break
print("\nYou missed", len(wrongAnswers), "words\n")


if len(wrongAnswers) > 0:  
 wrong = str(wrongAnswers)        
 output = input("Please name the file you would like you wrong answers to be saved in: ")
 outf = open(output, 'w')
 outf.write(wrong)
 outf.close()
else:
    print("You got all of the problems correct!")
```

main()

Comment: Seems to work fine for me with the dictionary = {'white':'blanco', 'purple':'morado'}. What does your dictionary look like?

Comment: @Sebastian it's in a txt file, and looks like this: red,rojo   
blue,azul   
yellow,amarillo
green,verde
purple,morado
orange,anaranjado
pink,rosa
white,blanco
black,negro
brown,marron

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Comment: @Sebastian okay, i posted.

Comment: Have you tried printing what dictionary looks like? You'll see it's not formatted as you intended.